# How to lock two JPA queries in Spring JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two queries :-

```
1. customerRepository.getCustomerList();
2. customerRepository.updateCustomerList();
```

I want to implement locking on both (Atomicity of the transaction) so that only single thread (http request) is allowed to do that transaction in JAVA.

I do not want to use the synchronous block of class level.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a public method somewhere which calls those two methods (directly or indirectly). You can annotate that method with `@Transactional` to force the database calls to run within one transaction.

See https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring